# Python: Extract substring that matches regular expression in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to fetch some database details from wp-config.php file.
Unfortunately I stick on the part where I have the line that contains the DB_NAME and I could not extract the **database_name** only from the following:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name');
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each line and then apply  `re.search` like below.

```
>>> x = "define('DB_NAME', 'database_name');"
>>> re.search(r"define\('DB_NAME',\s*'([^']*)'\);", x).group(1)
'database_name'
```

or

```
for line in f:
    if 'DB_NAME' in line:
        print line.split("'")[3]
```